# Ошибка с импортом AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-appcompat

Начал осваивать Android Studio, и нигде не могу найти ответ, как подключить AppCompat нужной версии, прошу подсказать в чем дело!

На скринах видно все версии, не понимаю, что не так.

...
Решил вопрос! Просто создал новый проект, в нем обновились библиотеки AppCompat, и уже ничего не горело красным, а в старом проекте почему то новая версия не предлагалась.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте пересобрать проект (Build=>Rebuild Project) и синхронизировать `gradle`. Так всё выглядит нормальным. Возможно buildtoolversion 28.0.0 при target 26 не даёт пересобрать `gradle`

Comment: У меня есть похожая беда в одном проекте, все билдится, но студия не видит классы из саппорт библиотеки. Пока не дошли руки разобраться :)

Comment: Скобки `{}` и имя параметра к методу добавьте: `onButtonClick(View view) {}`.